# disk usage of home directory is much larger than sum of disk usage of its sub-directories and files

Tags: linux, disk-space

Recently, the system (a desktop machine with Linux 5.18) reported disk space is nearly full. My machine has a 1TB ssd.

```
[zjs@manjaro ~]$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev              16G     0   16G   0% /dev
run              16G  1.7M   16G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2  916G  847G   23G  98% /
tmpfs            16G  331M   16G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G   22M   16G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p1  300M  288K  300M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3.1G   88K  3.1G   1% /run/user/1000
```

```
[zjs@manjaro ~]$ sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /
[sudo] password for zjs: 
0   /sys
0   /proc
18G /usr
12K /srv
8.3G    /var
1.7M    /run
16K /lost+found
71M /boot
4.7G    /opt
13M /etc
56K /tmp
0   /dev
4.0K    /mnt
817G    /home
16M /root
847G    /
```

```
[zjs@manjaro ~]$ du -h --max-depth=1 /home
817G    /home/zjs
817G    /home
```

It turned out that my home dir `/home/zjs` used much of the disk space, it used 817G. So I ran the following command to see the details,

```
[zjs@manjaro ~]$ du -sch * . [!.]* | sort -rh
817G    total
805G    .
6.2G    Downloads
3.8G    llvm-project
556M    cp
267M    Typora
210M    jhelper
150M    hugo
117M    TeXmacs
112M    go
37M cp2
26M cf-tool
24M node_modules
18M blog
17M slides
14M install-tl-20220616
3.5M    arc077e
1.7M    learn-go
1.3M    fontconfig
1.1M    arc077e.zip
788K    CLionProjects
264K    typical90025
216K    abc206e
40K Documents
32K Desktop
8.0K    typical90025.zip
8.0K    marp_slides
8.0K    learn-texmacs.tm~
8.0K    abc206e.zip
4.0K    # 数位乘积等式.md
4.0K    安装texlive.txt
4.0K    Videos
4.0K    tools
4.0K    texmacs笔记.md
4.0K    Templates
4.0K    Public
4.0K    Pictures
4.0K    package-lock.json
4.0K    package.json
4.0K    Music
4.0K    learn-texmacs.tm
4.0K    githubtokens.txt
4.0K    at2lg.py
0   typora_test.md
```

Directories and files inside `/home/zjs` used only 12G of disk space, so how is that extra 805G of disk space used? And how to fix this?

Restarting the system did not help.

Comment: The question is answered already: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9612/why-is-there-a-discrepancy-in-disk-usage-reported-by-df-and-du

Comment: Does `ncdu /home` report the same thing? Does the situation change after a reboot? Does `lsfd -Q deleted` show any files in /home?

Comment: @RomeoNinov This is a different question. In my case the disk usage reported by `df` and `du` don't differ much. I am asking why the reported disk usage of my home dir is much larger than sum of disk usage of its contained dirs and files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's the huge `.xsession-errors.old` file (870G). I should have noticed that hidden files and directories are not listed by `du -sch * . [!.]*`. To see disk usage of hidden files and directories one should use `du -sch .[!.]* *`, as noticed in this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/363681/722485.